# Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

Tags: debugging

I am essentially trying to build a list of strings, where each of those strings in turn are built by their own functions.

However, I get the following error when the code is evaluated:

> Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

Here is the code:

```
(defun mode-line-segment-git-status ()
  "Build the git status mode-line segment."
  (let (branch-name '(substring-no-properties vc-mode 5)))
  (list "Branch: " 'branch-name))


(defvar mode-line-segments nil)
(defun add-mode-line-segment (segment)
  "Add a modeline segment to the modeline."
  (setq mode-line-segments (append mode-line-segments (funcall segment))))

(add-mode-line-segment 'mode-line-segment-git-status)

(setq-default mode-line-format mode-line-segments)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `let` in your first function a) should enclosed your `let`-bound variable in its own set of parentheses, and b) should *not* quote the function whose value you want to bind to the variable.

Answer (score 5):

@Dan's comment is quite correct: you don't need to be quoting inside your `let` form, and also, you can't access `let`-bound variables outside the scope of the `let` form. (You might notice that Emacs lisp has a single global namespace for variables. `let` is how we encapsulate variables inside functions, keep them from leaking.)

More generally: the `Wrong type argument` is elisp's way of telling you, "I expected an `x` but got a `y`. `stringp, nil` means, "I expected something that satisfies the `stringp` predicate, but I received `nil`." You can get more information about where the error is happening by calling `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, but "I'm handing a `nil` to something that needs a string` might be enough of a hint.

Comment: +1 for `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`. It's really handy when you have a way of reliably reproducing the error.